# Target blank opens link in the same tab when inside a modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I'm using a bootstrap modal to show some text to the user. The modal has a button to go to a "printable version" of the content. I want that this link open in a new window, so I'm using `target="_blank"` attribute.

The problem is that the link opens in the same tab. It acts as a `_self` target.

I'm using Zend Framework.

The code to the `a` tag is:

```
$this->view->actions = array(array(
            'tag' => 'a'
            , 'label' => 'Versão para impressão'
            , 'attrs' => array(
                'href' => BASE_URL. '/corporativo/index/termos?layout=print', 
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-print', 
                'target' => '_blank'
            )
        ));
```

It generates the following html code:

```
<a href="http://localhost/corporativo/index/termos?layout=print" class="btn btn-primary btn-print" target="_blank">Versão para impressão</a>
```

Anyone knows why is this happening and any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Modal basically means a popup right? I think you've encountered a browser security feature to prevent popups from generating more popups.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting how I solved this problem as a reference for people that have the same issue.

Basically, I removed the `target` attribute and added an `onclick` with a `window.open` function in it. This will act like an usual `target="_blank"` tag for this specific case.

The code turned into this:

```
$this->view->actions = array(array(
            'tag' => 'a', 
            'label' => 'Versão para impressão', 
            'attrs' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-print', 
                'onclick' => "window.open('".BASE_URL. '/corporativo/index/termos?layout=print'."');"
                )
        ));
```

Which generates this html code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-print" onclick="window.open('http://localhost/corporativo/index/termos?layout=print');">Versão para impressão</a>
```

This worked perfectly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No need of adding any javascript code, instead of that just add an attribute to the anchor tag { data-skip="" }.

```
<a  data-skip="" target='_blank' href="some link"> your link text </a>.
```

It will be work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make this workaround:

```
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.modal-body a[target="_blank"]', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank'); //modal target _blank is not working
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It's must be problem with settings in your browser. HTML code working and link is opening in new window correctly.

Comment: I tested in Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and IE. All the browsers have the same behavior. What would I have to change to fix this?

Comment: Maybe antivirus blocking this, because your target="_blank" syntax is ok and its must working in all browsers.